# Onscreen Keyboard Won't Start?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, onscreen-keyboard

I have a server without a local keyboard, but it has a monitor. I use it for media display while I work. I can use the onscreen keyboard to log in, but after that going into settings, typing and turning on the On-Screen-Keyboard there does nothing... It lights up orange and says 'ON' but the keyboard never shows up.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly hackish, but after some searching I haven't been able to find a better solution. Ubuntu includes the on-screen keyboard `onboard` but opening it without a keyboard is apparently almost impossible.

### Open a Terminal

We need a terminal to execute the application. If it happens to be in your Dash or Launcher, then awesome! Otherwise follow the steps below.

1. Open `nautilus`
2. Browse to `/usr/bin`
3. Find `gnome-terminal`
4. Right-click and choose "Run"

### Run onboard

Onboard is apparently a Python application, so we can't just right-click it and choose "Run" like we did with the terminal. Instead, we'll need to use a trick to press "enter" in the terminal.

1. In the same directory as before find `onboard`
2. Click and drag the `onboard` file to the terminal window so that `'/usr/bin/onboard'` appears there
3. Place your cursor at the end of the line in the terminal and move down one line
4. This should select a newline character as shown below

   [image: Selecting a newline character]
5. Right-click the highlighted "text" and choose "Copy"
6. Deselect the newline by left-clicking in the terminal
7. Right-click in the terminal and choose "Paste"
8. The on-screen keyboard should appear

**IMPORTANT:** Don't close the terminal window; this will close `onboard` as well.